# Unity3D - Parent object follows as i move child object

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube, transform

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9jHSts2vPQ

so on this first video the gameObject(empty) is placed as a door hinge
now whenever i placed the door to the hinge as a child
the parent follows the child, what i want it to stay as normal i can move child freely without being followed by the parent, it will just stay at the child's middle point

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kgw700L5lQ

on this second video i tried to loophole it by moving the parent and child, now after doing i set the "hinge" into the correct position, then i move the child object(door) separately, now almost at the end of the video i moved the door in the correct position, and the "hinge" follows as i move the child

Comment: So what is your question? Update your post with the question

Answer (score 0):

set the **transform gizmo toggles** to **pivot** (see picture in link below). current you have set it to center, so its in the center of the bounds of the selected gameobject (including children). thats what causing the seemingly odd behaviour, though its actually working as expected :)

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html